# Scope variable not binding when change in firebase promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a controller function to submit a signup with firebase, but it seems that the variables from the scope (`controllerAs: $reg`) are not binding when they are updated inside the promise.

When `$reg.loading` is changed to **true**, it is correctly updated in the template, but when is changed to **false**, the scope variable is updated in the controller but the template ignores it.

```
$reg.submit = () => {
  $reg.loading = true;

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword($reg.user.email, $reg.user.password)
    .catch(error => {
      $reg.loading = false;
    });
};
```

The template is just a form where I call `$reg.submit()` function when the submit button is clicked (tested with both **ng-submit** & **ng-click**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found my error.

I was using `firebase` common object, which is not aware about I am using Angular, what I should use is the object `$firebaseAuth` (injected on the controller) from **AngularFire** library.

This way I have a promise worried about doing itself the $digest loop in Angular:

```
$reg.submit = () => {
  $reg.loading = true;

  $firebaseAuth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword($reg.user.email, $reg.user.password)
    .catch(error => {
      $reg.loading = false;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $scope.$apply()

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
   $reg.loading = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing scope to rootScope.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13705030)

Comment: I did try to answer what was asked here. I don't have reputation otherwise would have commented. And please don't ever discourage someone who is new to something. @cartant